Можно ли в Android 14 создать foreground service (location), который будет работать даже если пользователь закрыл приложение?
Сейчас с использованием .net MAUI пытаюсь написать приложение для Android для наблюдения за ребёнком. Написал приложение, которое по таймеру отправляет координаты устройства на сервер. Получение координат сделал в foreground service, всё работает, даже если приложение свёрнуто или телефон заблокирован. Но если приложение зарыть, foreground service завершается. Подскажите, можно ли сделать так, чтобы foreground service работал в фоне даже при закрытом приложении?

Если под приложение зарыть вы имеете в виду Force Stop из системных настроек - то, скорее всего, может помочь только рутование девайса и длее пробовать что-то типа делания приложения системным, чтобы его нельзя было остановить и/или чтобы оно рестартовало постоянно. Если вы имеете в виду просто смахивание приложения из списка запущенных приложений - то попробуйте всякие ему приоритеты повыставлять в его системных настройках - возможно это не позволит системе прибивать его сервис.

Спасибо. Я как раз имею ввиду смахивание из списка запущенных. Попробую, если получится, отпишусь.

Не знаю что нового по этой теме в Андроид 14, но в прошлом году (до выхода Андроид 14) у меня был BLE проект и foreground service вполне себе жил после смахивания приложения. Проверьте что он у вас не крашится, возможно слишком жестко связан с основным приложением.

Спасибо, попробую изолировать сервис максимально. Отпишусь, если получится.

Получилось! Проблема была в том, что приложению требовалось разрешение "Работать в фоновом режиме", которое пока не понятно как попросить у пользователя, но можно выставить руками в настройках Android на телефоне из меню "Безопасность" -> "Автозапуск в фоновом режиме". Плюс, что, тоже очень важно, вынес всю работу по отправке координат в метод, не связанный с основным сервисом. Спасибо вам большое за комментарии!
